# Splitting fields over $\mathbb{F}_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

> Let $f(x)=x^3+1\in\mathbb F_5[x]$. (a) Write $f$ as a product of irreducibles and construct a splitting field $\mathbb{K}\subseteq L$ for $f$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$. (b) Determine the extension degree $[L:\mathbb{F}_5]$.

My thoughts are that $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$ is such a product of irreducibles; the only way the quadratic factor would be reducible if it had a root in $\mathbb{F}_5$, but it is clear that no such root exists. Hence this is such a product. To construct a splitting field for $f$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$ we need to 'add' the roots of the polynomial which are not already in $\mathbb{F}_5$.

One root, $-1$, is certainly in $\mathbb{F}_5$ ($-1\equiv 4$ in $\mathbb{F}_5$). The other two roots are the roots of the quadratic factor, which are $\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-3}}{2}$, and these certainly are not in $\mathbb{F}_5$. If we were to have the elements $\{i,\sqrt{3}\}$, however, we would indeed be able to solve the equation in $L$. But how do we write this splitting field?

For (b), I suspect the answer is $4$, as the minimum polynomial of $i$ is $x^2+1$ and the m.p. of $\sqrt{3}$ is $x^2-3$, both of degree $2$.

Are these answers correct?

Comment: As you remark, the non-trivial roots of that cubic are *quadratic* over the base field.

Comment: I don't understand "$\mathbb{K}\subseteq L$": what are these two fields and which one is the splitting field?

Comment: I don't understand "K⊆L": what are these two fields and which one is the splitting field?

Answer (score 0):

Your factorization is correct but $[L:\mathbb F_5]=2.$

$L=\mathbb F_5[\sqrt{-3}].$

Comment: As in, $L=\mathbb{F}_5[i,\sqrt{3}]$? As it has 2 appended roots

Comment: Observe that $\sqrt{-1}$ is embedded into $\mathbb F_5$ because $2^2\equiv3^2\equiv-1$. So we never need to append $i$ at all, only $\sqrt{-3}$ (or $\sqrt3$).

Comment: Yes, and anyway $\sqrt{-1}$ is off topic (as well as $\sqrt3$).

Comment: @AnneBauval off topic?

Comment: Yes: we only need to append $\sqrt{-3},$ there is no reason to want to append $(\sqrt{-1},\sqrt3),$ or whatever pair of the form $(\sqrt a,\sqrt{-3/a}).$ A splitting field is the *smallest* extension over which $f$ splits.